# File not found exception in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to access config file in login page. Both are present at same level.

[image]

**Config File**

```
namespace config;

class AppConfig {
    private $domain = "domain/";
    private $absolutePath = "path/";
    public $completeDomain = $domain . $absolutePath;
}
```

**Login Page**

```
use config\AppConfig;

$config = new AppConfig();
```

**Error Message**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "config\AppConfig" not found

Am I missing anything?

Comment: A class is not a file. That's two completely different matters

Comment: You need to include the file that your `AppConfig` class resides in. Either through an autoloader or a `require_once` statement.

Comment: you need autoloader, otherwise you need to include classes by yourself